# Atributes for annotation ModelAtribute and PreAuthorize in Generic classes

Tags: java, spring, generics, service, controller

In my spring project, I am trying set up generic classes for my controllers and service classes, with commons methods used by that classes. In my generic controller, each possible action the entities could receive (like insert, update, delete, select), are implemented with a pair of methods like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'permission')")
public ModelAndView cadastra() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return new ModelAndView("privado/"+this.entity_name+"/cadastra", "command", this.entity.getClass().newInstance());
}
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(service.cadastra(object))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

and in my generic service class, this same action have related methods like that:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'permissao')")
public boolean cadastra(E object) {
    return dao.persist(object);
}
```

My question is which value I should use as atribute replacing `permission` and `object` above. The value for permssion follow this scheme:

```
<name_of_action>_<name_of_entity>
```

and the value for object is the name of each entity.

I try use the same structure I use inside the method (`+this.entity_name+`), but this cause an compilation error, because this annotations only accept constant arguments.

It was sugested to me use a generic class for my entities, but I can't figure out how to use that in my case.

Anyone can give a direction of how to accomplish what I want?

**UPDATE**

After some sugestions from other users from stackoverflow, I get to solve my problem with the ModelAtribute annotation. The final solution was this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

and I add this new method to my controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("object")
public E createCommandObject() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return (E) this.entityClass.newInstance();
}
```

Now I need only a solution for the PreAuthorize annotation, which uses the instruction #this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solve this issue with this approach:

1) For annotation PreAuthorize:

1.1) Adding a new method to my generic controller, where I return the name of the class:

```
public String getName() {
    String expressao = entityClass.getName();
    String nome_classe = new String();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao, ".");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nome_classe = st.nextToken();
    }
    return nome_classe;
}
```

1.2) Inside the annotation, I use the returned value by this method and concatenate the result with the constant string (using the notation described by the user @pgjecek in this topic):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
```

and now it1s working perfectly.

2) For annotation ModelAtribute:

I keep using the form `@ModelAttribute("object") E object`, but add the method:

```
@ModelAttribute("object")
public E createCommandObject() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return (E) this.entityClass.newInstance();
}
```

which return a new instance of the desired object.